# What is a good way to approach a Rails 2.3 refactoring and port it to Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refactoring, port

I have to refactor a huge badly written (big controller methods), untested and undocumented Rails 2.3-Webapp and port it to Rails 3.

I can't simply move everything to rails 3 because parts of the app are selfmade plugins which nest controllers in controllers which is (as i was told) not possible in rails 3 because the used plugin for that isn't compatible.

Any hints how i should start? Or a little roadmap? 
Should I first try to write a documentation?
Then tests?

Best regards

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Language                      files          blank        comment           code
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Javascript                      231           9679           6538          42954
Ruby                            601           5540           3032          28417
HTML                             68           1172            266          13179
CSS                              80           1796            805           7677
XML                              17             69             63           1299
YAML                             36            114            216           1212
Bourne Shell                     12             77            226            343
MXML                              1              7              0             52
PHP                               2             29             28             26
Bourne Again Shell                1              9             29             17
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SUM:                           1049          18492          11203          95176
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I'd do it:

- Add tons of tests because you want to "save" how your application works and be sure it works even after the migration to rails 3
- Port old plugins to a rails 3 compatible version or drop them for better ones
- Add even more tests
- Upgrade to the latest version of Rails 2 so you get closer to rails 3, get all the deprecation notices and so on.
- More tests
- Upgrade to Rails 3 and fix tests that broke

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may have inherited the codebase. Another step on top of “Add Tests” I would suggest is take a deep look at all the tables for the project (hopefully with production data or a fascimile thereof) and look for any WTFs. it is often illuminating to track down the code that uses those WTFs. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have done some refactoring of very bad Rails apps and writing tests was always a big step forward. After this you will have a far better knowledge of the code base, you'll have found several small (and maybe large) bugs and you can feel far better about making changes to the code while updating it to Rails 3 since it's less likely that you break anything important. You don't need to test every details yet, but all the main functionality. In addition this gives you a nice set of fixtures (if that doesn't exist yet)